# dismissGrantingAccessToURL: failing with "didPickDocumentURLs called with nil or 0 URLS"

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios11

I have an iOS application that is providing Document Picker feature working perfectly on iOS 10 but that on iOS 11 always calls the `documentPickerWasCancelled:` with this message in logs:

> [UIDocumentLog] UIDocumentPickerViewController : didPickDocumentURLs
>   called with nil or 0 URLS

I'm correctly calling  `dismissGrantingAccessToURL:` with a valid NSURL on the provider extension but it never calls the `documentPicker:didPickDocumentsAtURLs:` on the other side.

I think I'm missing something, can you give me an explanation for this bad behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having the same problems. Unfortunately I think the explanation is a bug or backwards-incompatibility in iOS 11. According to the documents it should be enough with a Document Picker extension:

"The Document Picker View Controller extension can perform import and export operations on its own. If you want to support open and move operations, you must pair it with a File Provider extension."

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentpickerextensionviewcontroller?language=objc

And indeed this worked fine in iOS 10 and earlier. iOS 11 was probably meant to be backwards compatible with the existing FileProvider-less DocumentPickers, but seems it's not. Or perhaps they forgot to update the documents.

Instead, one can implement the new updated File Provider that gives access to your files via the standard document browser UI:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/fileprovider

Comment: Thank you, I see that Dropbox, that had the same problem, updated their application with a new File Provider and I will follow their same choice.

Answer (score 0):

This does work with an iOS 11 FileProvider backing the iOS10 picker.  You probably want to create a new FileProvider using the new Xcode template, then use :

```
@available(iOSApplicationExtension 11.0, *)
```

on the FileProviderItem and FileProviderEnumerator classes, then :

```
if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 11.0, *) {
```

in the methods on your FileProviderExtension

I find that my iOS 10 picker does correctly call this method, but note the completionHandler?(nil) was required to make it work.  By default, the template for iOS11 inserts a completion that reports a failure.  This code works for me:

```
    override func startProvidingItem(at url: URL, completionHandler: ((_ error: Error?) -> Void)?) {

            completionHandler?(nil)

    //        completionHandler?(NSError(domain: NSCocoaErrorDomain, code: NSFeatureUnsupportedError, userInfo:[:]))

}
```

However, that isn't the end to this iOS10/11 incompatibility.  If you make an iOS10/11 compatible file provider, it won't run on some iOS10 devices as far as I can see.  I can run or debug mine on a 32-bit iOS device, but the FileProvider crashes on a 64-bit iOS 10 device with this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/FileProvider.framework/FileProvider
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/61BBD1A7-EA1E-4C10-A208-CA1DFA433C8D/test.app/PlugIns/testFileProvider.appex/testFileProvider
  Reason: image not found
```